# Uncaught TypeError: JSON.parse(...).steam.toFixed is not a function

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 functions on the site, when the user exchanges items from Dota 2 through the Steam API, price is being parsed via json: `$("#steam").text( + ${JSON.parse(data).steam.toFixed(2)} ₽).fadeIn(500).animate({ opacity: "100" }, 500);`.

2 decimal after dot are displayed perfectly, and there is a function of transferring money between users, where the same piece of code is used. So, the problem is that when I try to transfer money, at console, I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: JSON.parse(...).steam.toFixed is not a function`, if i remove `.toFixed(2)` from code and try to transfer money, all display great, but when i excange items from Dota through Steam, it can be displayed `1.000000000001` it’s because of this that I use `.toFixed(2)`.

The question is, how can I use `.toFixed(2)` at this two situations and don't receive an error?

**EDIT:** for some reason I cut a little code, here is normal code:

```
$("#steam").text(` + ${JSON.parse(data).steam.toFixed(2)} ₽`).fadeIn(500)
.animate({ opacity: "100" }, 500);
```

Comment: What other types of values can `steam` property be? That error indicates that it might not always be a number. Try `parseFloat(JSON.parse(data).steam).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano exactly here `steam` has only numbers, nothing more

Comment: Could you edit your question and put your code in context? As far as I see your string literal has wrong syntax. Should be `\`+ ${JSON.parse(data).steam.toFixed(2)}\``

Comment: yes, i use it, for some reason I cut a little code, i edit question and pit my code

Comment: The steam property clearly is *not* a number, at least some of the time. What do you want to display if it's not? Is there a reasonable default e.g. zero? If not you'll have to decide what to show the user.

Comment: if 0 or <1 i show to user popup window with information, that min. - 1, and at input field i use `number` type, nothing can be and will not accept anything else

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `parseFloat(JSON.parse(data).steam)?.toFixed(2);`

Keep in mind, that doing it this way, could result in errors, or display issues if data does not contain steam, or steam is an invalid value.

I would suggest adding logic before this part, to test your data, and return exceptions as required, or fix the data by displaying `0.00`, or whatever your default should be.

Here is an example:

```
var data = "{ \"steam\": \"1000.1\" }";

var obj = JSON.parse(data);

var value = obj.steam !== null ? parseFloat(obj.steam) : 0;

value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;

console.log(` + ${value} ₽`);
```